# Don't understand the set for all positive odd integers in set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have: $X = \{x \in \mathbb{N} : x − 2 \in X\} \cup \{1\}$ and this is the set for all positive odd numbers but I don't quite understand.

The way I've read it is that for an integer $x$, that is part of the set of natural numbers, to be in the set $X$.... And that's where I get stuck.

I don't quite get how $x - 2$ could be in the set $X$ if we're currently making it so surely a set wouldn't be made? And isn't the last part just adding 1 to the list or am I missing something?

Comment: You can use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Comment: Intuitively, $1 \in X$ and then with $x=3$ we have that $3-2=1$, and thus we have to "throw in" also $3$, and so on.

Comment: We may write, more simply: $X = \{ 2k+1 \mid k \in \mathbb N \}$ (where $\mathbb N = \{ 0, 1, 2, \ldots \}$.

Comment: Would it help to switch the order in the definition? You can always do that with the union. The definition could read then, intuitively, "X includes 1, and if x - 2 is in the set then so is x."

Comment: @MBP: Also important to the intuition is that $\mathbb{N}$ has a bottom end which ensures everything reduces to the base case. Replace $\mathbb{N}$ with $\mathbb{Z}$ and the formula no longer uniquely defines a set. In addition to the positive odd integers, the solutions include the set of all odd integers, the set of all integers and the set of all integers except the negative odd ones. I think that exhausts the possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking of this definition as "building" a set piece by piece is very much the wrong metaphor to apply here.

What you have is an *equation* that a set $X$ might satisfy. It's an equation in the language of set theory rather than in the language of arithmetic, but it's still an equation.

And, as it turns out, the equation has a unique solution, so we can define $X$ to be that solution.

Answer (score 0):

The definition is a bit weird in that it is self-referential . But it is perfectly valid

notice that $X \subseteq \Bbb N$ since it is the union of two sets contained in $\Bbb N$

Also notice that the set defined as $X = \{ x \in \mathbb N \mid x-2 \in X \}$ is the empty set, but explicitly including $\{ 1 \}$ doesn't just add that element, it changes the definition of the first set to include all odd numbers.